# Proving that a surface is a plane

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Hey everyone I'm loosing my mind on this one..

Let's say we have a a parametric surface:

$A(u,v) = (u^2+v^2,u^2-v^2,uv)$

and we want to determine whether it is a plane or not. From what I understand if we compute the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial }{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial }{\partial v}$ in this case:

$\vec{n_1}=\frac{\partial }{\partial u} = (2u,2u,v)$ and $\vec{n_2} = \frac{\partial }{\partial v} = (2v,-2v,u)$

these will be two vectors defining the normal plane of the the surface at a point A(u,v). Their cross product is the normal vector at that point, in this case:

$\vec{n} = (2u,2u,v) \times (2v,-2v,u) = (2u^2+2v^2,2v^2-2u^2,-8uv)$

Well, if the surface is a plane shouldn't the normal vector have the same gradient at every point on the surface? Which means there should be a vector $\vec{w} = \left \langle x,y,z \right \rangle$ such that the normal vector $\vec{n} $ could be expressed as a scalar of $\vec{w}$ :

$\vec{n} = (a,b,c) \cdot \vec{w}$

Am I missing something here? Is there such a way to express $\vec{n}$?

Comment: Then the conclusion you would make is that it is not a plane, right? For example $n(1,0,0) = (2,-2,0)$ but $n(0,1,0) = (2,2,0)$

Comment: if a surface is a plane then its normal vector must be constant everywhere, for instance $\tan(\frac{x}{y})$ would be a constant

Comment: this follows from the fact that any plane has the form $x⋅a=0$ where a is the normal vector, any x in this plane will then be perpendicular to the normal vector and hence the set of points satysfing this relation define a plane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: With some algebraic manipulation you can get that the cartesian equation of the surface is

$$x^2-y^2-4z^2=0$$

This is a cone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain briefly what manipulations you did to find this equation? Also you are absolutely right it's definitely a cone there must be some error in my textbook

Comment: @VakiPitsi what is $x+y$? $x-y$?